# TableToTable (CSV to GDB) with WKT column

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7

I have a CSV file with a WKT column with LINESTRINGS as geometry.

How do I setup the call to TableToTable() in order to directly "transform" that WKT column to a shape/geometry column (while ignoring the original WKT column from the CSV file in the final GDB)?

Can it be done using FieldMappings?

Unfortunately, I am limited to Python 2.7 and ArcMap 10.8.

Comment: @BERA yes, I found this stackoverflow: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259817/convert-wkt-to-layer-arcpy which shows how to solve it using InsertCursor, but I was hoping for a more "direct" way.

Comment: TableToTable only copies tables. If you source a feature class, it drops the geometry column in the target, so all you can do with FieldMapping is drop the WKT column. Using an InsertCursor has to be way easier than using Append, then joining to the source to populate geometry.